# Combine columns from a table into a JSON object

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a table in athena with data

```
type   state   city  zipcode
-------------------------------
hot     az     phx    85281
hot     tx     dal    12345
cool    wa     sea    67890
cool    ny     nyc    67856
```

I want the output to be like

```
type   Data 
-------------
hot    {state: az, city:phx, zipcode: 85281}
hot    {state: tx, city:dal, zipcode: 12345}
cool   {state: wa, city:sea, zipcode: 67890}
cool   {state: ny, city:nyc, zipcode: 67856}
```

I am trying to use the aggregate function but i'm unable to use it.

SELECT type, CAST(MAP(ARRAY['state', 'city', 'zipcode'], ARRAY[state,city,zipcode] ) AS JSON) FROM "test"."alldata"

but the query fails.

Comment: Why are there only 3 rows in your result and not 4?

Comment: Ideally it should have 4. just an example. Modified it

Comment: Are you looking for a MySQL solution, or an Athena solution? Please tag only the relevant database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hive:

```
with mydata as (
select stack(4,
    'hot', 'az', 'phx', 85281,
    'hot', 'tx', 'dal', 12345,
    'cool', 'wa', 'sea', 67890,
    'cool', 'ny', 'nyc', 67856
) as  (type, state, city, zipcode)
)

select type, map('state', state, 'city', city,'zipcode',zipcode) as data
 from mydata;
```

Result:

```
type    data
hot     {"state":"az","city":"phx","zipcode":"85281"}
hot     {"state":"tx","city":"dal","zipcode":"12345"}
cool    {"state":"wa","city":"sea","zipcode":"67890"}
cool    {"state":"ny","city":"nyc","zipcode":"67856"}
```

If you need string type, use [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) library:

```
add jar /path/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar; --compile jar and load it to the distributed cache
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';

select type, to_json(map('state', state, 'city', city,'zipcode',zipcode)) as data
 from mydata;
```

Comment: I was trying to use 
select type, collect_set(to_json(map('state', state, 'city', city,'zipcode',zipcode))) as addData group by  `type`  from mydata ;

Required O/p.
```
hot , [
{"state":"az","city":"phx","zipcode":"85281"}, 
{"state":"tx","city":"dal","zipcode":"12345"}
]

cool, [
{"state":"wa","city":"sea","zipcode":"67890"}, {"state":"ny","city":"nyc","zipcode":"67856"}
]
```
When i try to use collect_set, it throws me

The exception is Attribute name "collect_set(addData)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

Comment: @Vinny Use collect() brickhouse function.  collect(map(....)) - this will produce array of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mysql Version with 5.7 or higher : use

```
SELECT `type`,json_object('state', `state`, 'city', `city`,'zipcode',`zipcode`)
FROM alldata;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE alldata
>     (`type` varchar(4), `state` varchar(2), `city` varchar(3), `zipcode` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO alldata
>     (`type`, `state`, `city`, `zipcode`)
> VALUES
>     ('hot', 'az', 'phx', 85281),
>     ('hot', 'tx', 'dal', 12345),
>     ('cool', 'wa', 'sea', 67890),
>     ('cool', 'ny', 'nyc', 67856)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `type`,json_object('state', `state`, 'city', `city`,'zipcode',`zipcode`)
> FROM alldata;
> ```
>
> ```
> type | json_object('state', `state`, 'city', `city`,'zipcode',`zipcode`)
> :--- | :----------------------------------------------------------------
> hot  | {"city": "phx", "state": "az", "zipcode": 85281}                 
> hot  | {"city": "dal", "state": "tx", "zipcode": 12345}                 
> cool | {"city": "sea", "state": "wa", "zipcode": 67890}                 
> cool | {"city": "nyc", "state": "ny", "zipcode": 67856}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=39a9ecc2d604281004120ba5483b7322)*